# WPF Dispatcher not releasing object for GC

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks, dispatcher

I'm trying to track down some memory leaks in my application and according the the ANTS profiler, many of my objects are being help up by System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher. My application is basically single threaded and the only explicit calls I make to Dispatcher.Invoke are unrelated to the objects being held up. The objects do seem to all be UserControl children of a FixedDocument subclass of mine, if that means anything to anyone.

[image]

What is causing the dispatcher to not release my objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an operation scheduled on the dispatcher (e.g., with `BeginInvoke`), and one of the arguments to that operation references your `ReportVisualTable`, either directly or indirectly.

Looking at the types included in your retention graph, it looks like a `DocumentViewer` attempted to bring a page into view, but the page hadn't been loaded yet, so the operation was deferred on the dispatcher.  The operation was enqueued at priority level `Inactive`, which means it will just sit in the queue indefinitely, because that priority level is never processed.  When the requested page is loaded, the operation's priority is bumped up to `Background`, but if that never happens, it seems the operation will just stay inactive.

Comment: Is there a way I can force that operation to execute so it releases the object? Right now it seems to sit around indefinitely.

Comment: Are you removing some document from the visual tree almost immediately after it is added?  This may be a design flaw in the document viewer.  After the requested page is loaded, it's support to change the operation's priority to `Background`.  If that doesn't happen, it looks like it will stay in the queue forever.

Comment: Maybe that is it ... there's no built-in functionality (that I can find) to remove pages so right now removing a page involes rebuilding the whole document. If I'm removing 2+ pages at a time the document with change in quick succession.

Comment: You could try deferring the removal by scheduling it on the dispatcher at a priority of `Loaded`; if that doesn't help, try `Background`.  Beware of creating similar memory leaks or data races if you go that route :).

Comment: Thanks! I have some work to fix the problem but at least now I know what the problem is.